# UX question for pricing packages pages

Tags: website-design, gui-design, lean-ux, ux-designer

[image]

On pricing package pages if we are giving the customer an option to customize the price for the package what's the best way it should be handled to give the best user experience for the user?

I guess it can be a popup or maybe under the pricing packages we can have customized it to your preference text and once its clicked, we can use Ajax to drop down a text box where they can customize the package price. The last option is a slider, but I don't really like sliders. Lets see what other experts can add to this conversation.

Comment: If you need an example and can read German, see http://www.congstar.de/handytarife/. They do implement it similarly to Drew Beck's suggestion, but with a bit more distinction between the normal plans and the "plan building block set".

Answer (score 4):

Custom is a type of plan, right? Then it should be another plan select button, like so:

[image: Custom plan select]

The Custom Plan link takes you to a plan customization page.

Alternately, you could do a tab-style jQuery slidedown, whereby clicking Custom Plan reveals the customization interface, like so:

[image: Tab-style custom plan select.]